# Retrieve all triggered send definitions across all BUs in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm trying to retrieve all the triggered send definitions for all the business units my user has access to in order to integrate them elsewhere. For some reason I'm only getting back the ones for my default BU.

Here is my request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken >
            <wsse:Username></wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password></wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">;
        <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>TriggeredSendDefinition</ObjectType>
                <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
                <Properties>Name</Properties>
                <Properties>Client.ID</Properties>
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Is there any filter I need to add to expand the request to all BUs? From the documentation it said leaving the filter null will return all MIDs so I'm kind of at a loss with this.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to my question. I was missing

```
<QueryAllAccounts>true</QueryAllAccounts>
```